# What is the version of Apache Camel used in Akka 2.1?

Tags: apache, frameworks, version, integration, akka

I am looking at using Akka camel in a mission critical app.
what is the version of Apache Camel used in current Akka 2.1?
How can I used the latest Apache Camel in Akka?

Answer (score 1):

From the [Akka dependencies](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/v2.1.0/project/AkkaBuild.scala#L664), it seems that akka-camel uses Apache Camel 2.10.0:

```
val camelCore = "org.apache.camel" % "camel-core" % "2.10.0" exclude("org.slf4j", "slf4j-api") // ApacheV2
```